# Setting the profile_batch argument in the TensorBoard callback

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorboard

I am exploring the TensorFlow Profiler with the Keras TensorBoard callback. I have tried a bunch of different range values for the profile_batch argument but the Profiler seems to shows the following only:

[image]

[image]

Here's [a gist](https://gist.github.com/sayakpaul/559ec43cc0329b1edcb25ec8f306dfba) to reproduce this. I appreciate any help.

**Edit**:

I should have provided this information that on Google Colab it perfectly works after uninstalling TensorBoard 2.1.1, and installing `tb-nightly` and the TensorFlow Profiler Plugin. But on a notebook run on a Cloud Provider it might not work without setting up the CUDA Drivers (specifically, CUPTI) properly. Qiumin from the TensorFlow Profiler team helped me out in [this discussion thread](https://groups.google.com/a/tensorflow.org/d/msgid/discuss/CAGa_XGFNxo1rYgFu1EOqknfOsns7HHxbm0KN-7hNwMsiGbvddw%40mail.gmail.com?utm_medium=email&utm_source=footer).

Answer (score 2):

I executed the code in **Google Colab** using the code included your [**Gist**](https://gist.github.com/sayakpaul/559ec43cc0329b1edcb25ec8f306dfba) and followed the **Tensorflow Profiler Documentation** in this [link](https://www.tensorflow.org/tensorboard/tensorboard_profiling_keras).

You should check your **TensorFlow**, **Tensorboard**, and **TensorFlow Profiler** versions.

Run this snippet as indicated in the Documentation to ensure **latest** versions.

```
# Uninstall twice to uninstall both the 1.15.0 and 2.1.0 version of TensorFlow and TensorBoard. 
!pip uninstall -y -q tensorflow tensorboard
!pip uninstall -y -q tensorflow tensorboard
!pip install -U -q tf-nightly tb-nightly tensorboard_plugin_profile
```

When you run the Tensorboard and still don't see the **Profile** Tab, you could execute this snippet then restart the Tensorboard (killing the process).

```
!pip install -U tensorboard_plugin_profile
```

Here are the few code snippets I added.

Based on the documentation.

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
from __future__ import division
from __future__ import print_function

from datetime import datetime
from packaging import version

import os
```

```
# Imports
from tensorflow.keras.applications import MobileNetV2
from tensorflow.keras.layers import *
from tensorflow.keras.models import *

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline


import tensorflow as tf
print(tf.__version__)    # This should return 2.2.0-dev20200408 (as of date ) or higher
```

Check whether GPU is available.

```
device_name = tf.test.gpu_device_name()
if not device_name:
  raise SystemError('GPU device not found')
print('Found GPU at: {}'.format(device_name))
```

Used to run the Tensorboard.

```
# Launch TensorBoard and navigate to the Profile tab to view performance profile
%tensorboard --logdir=logs
```

If successfully executed it should display close to the image below. ( Note: Reduced the number of Epochs to 5 for faster training )

[image: tensorprofiler]

Hope this will help you.
If needed I could edit and provide the full **Google Colab Notebook code**.